# Failed attempt to fetch logical page - tempdb

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

At least 2 times a week I get an error as the tempdb should be corrupt.

> Failed attempt to fetch logical page xxxx in database 2.

This on all my 8 SQL Servers 2008 R2.

The strange thing is that after the error, users can continue to work without any problem. And using the corrupted tempdb for months... I don't find any topics where you talk about this, is this a bug? Or real corruption?

I found as only solution people reccomend restarting the service, something I don't want to do.

Comment: Could it be a disk error?

Answer (score 1):

Repeated corruption = faulty IO subsystem. Something, somewhere in the IO stack (driver, cache, controller, disk, etc)

I'd suggest that you get it onto a different IO subsystem to start with and investigate from there.